# How to calculate flux in a helical wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vectors, calculus, inductance

We have a wire going around in a helix (just like an inductor)  and a constant magnetic field exists along its axis throughout the space.

How do we calculate the flux through it? I can't understand where are the area elements upon which to calculate $\int B \cdot da$.

Comment: I suppose that by "constant" you mean in space not in time. In this case the proper term is "uniform".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In Figure-01 we have a solenoid of 1 turn. In case of uniform magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$  parallel to the axis of the helical wire the flux through the helical surface is equal to the flux through its projection on the $xy-$plane that is the circle shown. This equality, which is exact and not approximate, is proved  in the Figure-03 below.

[image]

In Figure-02 we have a solenoid of 4 turns.

[image]

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{cases}
\mathrm d\Phi_{\mathrm S}=\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm d \mathbf{S}=\mathrm B\mathrm{ d S}\cos\theta \\
\mathrm d\Phi_{\Sigma}=\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm d \boldsymbol{\Sigma}=\mathrm B\mathrm d \Sigma
\end{cases}\right\}\quad \stackrel{\mathrm d \Sigma=\mathrm{ d S}\cos\theta  }{=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow\:}\mathrm d\Phi_{\mathrm S}=\mathrm d\Phi_{\Sigma}
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}

[image]

Figure-01.a was added a posteriori in order for the boundary of the helical wire of Figure-01 to be more clear.

[image]

Video : [How to calculate flux in a helical wire](https://youtu.be/teQ27l_EcKo).

Comment: Thanks the images are clear, but what makes you determine the surface as such, as is shown in the figure. There exist infinite surfaces connected to a helix and the one above is one of them. How is this unique and only this should be used to calculate the flux?

Comment: Thank you dear Frobenius,I'm waiting to upvote it :)

Comment: Well done! Beautiful diagrams. This is what I was trying to explain in my far inferior answer. But although the orange surface 'feels right', I share Yasir Sadiq's uneasiness: why in particular should the the inner edge of the surface not extend beyond the helix axis?

Comment: I suspect that I'm having problems visualising properly in 3D. There's nothing you can do about that. Perhaps it will eventually 'click'! Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Frobenius and Philip Wood.

Comment: @Frobenius Great diagrams but the complete loop which encloses the **closed** area that you have coloured blue needs to be completed.  So in your Figure - 01 you need to add a vertical and a horizontal blue line.  For my attempt at a pictorial answer I had to resort to copper wire and a soap film, [Magnetic flux linkage of a solenoid is equal to BAN, but what is A representing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459470/magnetic-flux-linkage-of-a-solenoid-is-equal-to-ban-but-what-is-a-representing/459488#459488). How did you generate you lovely figures?

Comment: @Frobenius Which software did you use to produce such lovely diagrams?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you'd have no difficulty working out the flux linked with a closed circular loop if the flux density is uniform and normal to the plane containing the loop.

With a long solenoid (a helix of small pitch) of $n$ turns we usually treat each turn as a circular loop having, in the case you present, a flux $\Phi=\vec B. \vec A =BA$ through it. The flux *linkage* with the complete solenoid is then taken to be $nBA$.

Treating a helix as a series of closed loops may be thought unsatisfactory. I'm attracted to a bit of topological cleverness that regards the helix not as having $n$ disc-like surfaces, but as a single surface with $n$ folds, each of area very nearly equal to the disc area. Hard to describe and even harder to draw, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hello Philip, nice to meet again. Yes it's easy to compute flux for closed loops but flux in a  helix is absurd to me because there is no definite surface to it imo.

Comment: @Yasir Sadiq  Yes indeed. I tried to tackle your concern in my last paragraph, but I freely admit that my explanatory powers aren't up to it!