# Magnetic flux through a coil

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

We say that magnetic flux through a coil of area A is
$\phi=BAcos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $A$ and $B$ 
but my doubt is we can only take a flux through a closed-loop but there is no cloesd loop in coil
[image]

so how do we can say there is a flux linked with the coil 
I have the same doubt with a solenoid [image]
please help me I am having trouble

Comment: Related : [How to calculate flux in a helical wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/587995/how-to-calculate-flux-in-a-helical-wire/588071#588071).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area under consideration does not have to be defined by a complete **conducting** circuit.  The point is that an emf can be induced even if there is no induced current because the circuit under consideration is not conducting.
In you first diagram the circuit could be completed by imagining a non-conducting link across the left hand part of the coil within your dashed circle.

My answer to the question [Magnetic flux linkage of a solenoid is equal to BAN, but what is A representing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459470/magnetic-flux-linkage-of-a-solenoid-is-equal-to-ban-but-what-is-a-representing/459488#459488) illustrates how you can define an area for a complete conducting circuit which would entail you completing the two digrams that you have drawn.

Comment: Farcher that is what i originally thought. but since no current in the wire would actually cross this path as its not conducting.  yes although there would be an effective emf on this path, it would NOT be the same emf  if you were to take the path the encomlasses the ENTIRE circuit (the emf you actually want to calculate)(,also a valid path) as potentials are not defined and is dependant on the path you take. this assumed you want to find the emf of the actual path you take ( your circuit)

Comment: But think of it in terms of each component part of the whole conducting circuits and which bits of the circuit contribute most to the total emf which is generator. In a generator the leads connecting a coil to the outside world would not make much of a contribution.

Comment: yes, what i thought aswell ( read my other comment) but i thought id mention it to show that there would be 2 different emfs thst youd calculate for a fuller understanding. however yes both would be pretty much identicle and therefore irrelevant :)

Comment: I am thankful for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

instead of taking your closed loop to be the actual discontinuous square that you have drawn. take the loop to be the ENTIRE circuit. notice that the part of the circuit.nowhere near the coil would have a small contribution to the magnetic flux and thus would most likely be zero. its just easier to say that its the loop that is near the magnetic field as it prettu much is the same result